# How to add different styles for different select2 items in same page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I'm using 3 select2 elements in same page. I want to add different style to all. (height,width,placeholder etc..) But there is a problem with that causes on select2 css classes. When ı'm change a select-attribtution, changes every select elements in page.

Here is my HTML and CSS;

```css
.city #city-ch .select2-selection--single {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
 <div class="city">
                 <span id="city-img"><img src="images/city-icon.png" alt="icon-location"></span>
       <div id="form">
           <label for="city-ch">City</label>
          <select id="city-ch" class="js-example-basic-single "style="width:100%" name="city">
                 <optgroup label="A">
                    <option value="1">a</option>
                    <option value="2">b</option>
                 </optgroup>
                 <optgroup label="B">
                    <option value="3">c</option>
                    <option value="4">d</option>
                 </optgroup>
          </select>     
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="state">
                 <span id="state-img"><img src="images/state-icon.png" alt="icon-location"></span>
       <div id="form2">
           <label for="state-ch">State</label>
          <select id="state-ch" class="js-example-basic-single "style="width:100%" name="state">
                 <optgroup label="A">
                    <option value="1">a</option>
                    <option value="2">b</option>
                 </optgroup>
                 <optgroup label="B">
                    <option value="3">c</option>
                    <option value="4">d</option>
                 </optgroup>
          </select>     
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="category">
                 <span id="category-img"><img src="images/category-icon.png" alt="icon-location"></span>
       <div id="form3">
           <label for="category-ch">Category</label>
          <select id="category-ch" class="js-example-basic-single "style="width:100%" name="category">
                 <optgroup label="A">
                    <option value="1">a</option>
                    <option value="2">b</option>
                 </optgroup>
                 <optgroup label="B">
                    <option value="3">c</option>
                    <option value="4">d</option>
                 </optgroup>
          </select>     
      </div>
  </div>
```

These css features for first select2 element affects other select2 elements on page. I use unique id for each. But still the same thing.. Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks..

Comment: This part of your selector looks odd `.select2-selection--single`. Are you sure the double `--` is supposed to be there? Also I don't see that used anywhere in the HTML.

Comment: @pmahomme yes select2's some special class names have double --

Comment: Ok. It'd be helpful if you could create a jsFiddle that reproduces this.